# Prolog: Building a completely balanced tree

Tags: prolog

Does anyone know of any simpler ways of building completely balanced trees in Prolog?

Here's one solution I've found but I'm wondering if anyone knows of any simpler solutions?

This one is pretty simple but took me a little while to grasp exactly how it works.

Thanks :).

```
% from given solution

cbal_tree( 0, nil ) :- !.
cbal_tree( N, t(x,L,R) ) :- 
    N > 0,

    N0 is N - 1, % if N is 4, this would be 3

    N1 is N0 mod 2, % if N is 4, this would be 3 mod 2 = 1
    N2 is N0 - N1, % if N is 4, this would be 3-1= 2

    distrib( N1, N2, LeftNode, RightNode ),

    cbal_tree( LeftNode, L ), 
    cbal_tree( RightNode, R ).

distrib(N,N,N,N) :- !.
distrib(N1,N2,N1,N2). % giving these two clauses (*) 1,2,?,? could give 1,2 or 2,1
distrib(N1,N2,N2,N1). % (*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This build symmetric trees:

```
symm_tree(nil,0).
symm_tree(t(L,R),Level) :-
    Level > 0,
    M is Level-1,
    symm_tree(L,M),
    symm_tree(R,M).
```

Adding labels to the nodes should be trivial.

The code you posted can be slightly simplified to

```
cbal_tree(0, nil).
cbal_tree(N, t(x,L,R)) :- 
    N > 0,
    N0 is N - 1,    % -1 to account for root node
    N1 is N0 mod 2,
    N2 is N0 - N1,

    permutation([N1,N2], [NLeft,NRight]),

    cbal_tree(NLeft, L),
    cbal_tree(NRight, R).
```

but this is really how simple it gets, and the `distrib/3` handling of duplicates is gone.

Comment: Thanks larsmans.  I see what you're getting at.  However, it hangs if you ask for another solution and my tree notation is t(x,L,R) where x is a root node.  Other than that.. much more simple.

Comment: Edited. This was really a very quick hack.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is wrong.

Consider the case when N=5. The one subtree takes as argument the number 4 and the other the number 0. That is not a balanced tree.

Instead, I propose the following code:

```
cbal_tree(0, nil).
cbal_tree(N, t(x,L,R)) :-
    N > 0,
    N0 is N - 1,    % -1 to account for root node
    N1 is N0 div 2,
    N2 is N0 - N1,
    (N mod 2 =\= 0 -> permutation([N1,N2], [NLeft,NRight]) ;
                      [N1, N2] = [NLeft, NRight]),
    cbal_tree(NLeft, L),
    cbal_tree(NRight, R).
```

The if statement is to prevent backtracking from bringing you duplicate answers.

Please consider heavily marking this as an accepted answer because the answer provided is confusing at least.

Comment: without yet reading any of the Q and As on this page, the main purpose of having your tree balanced is to keep its depth in check. with that goal in mind, it's actually an acceptable solution to have left (say) child fully loaded and the right one almost empty. Consider 8 elements for example. 7 make 3 levels of the fully loaded tree. One extra element put as the root makes it 4 levels deep. it is still about ~ log n, so it's OK compared with the degenerate ~ n case which is really what we're trying to avoid here. And in what other way could we add our 8th element? Open up the new /contd.

Comment: the new, *4th* level? see, it doesn't change much. And what if we anticipate having to grow our tree a lot during the program's run time, by one element at a time? then it becomes crucial that we add each new element *easily*... --- Will now have to  read what's here; maybe my comment is off the mark, we'll see. :)

Comment: OK, having now read through this, indeed you were right, and your answer fixes the problem - which, I think, was just a typo, BTW. You haven't explained it fully with your example; the real problem is that with `mod` it would *always* produce only the degenerate trees (i.e. almost fully *lists*, not just unbalanced trees). preventing the duplicates was a nice touch; a side note: `N mod 2 =\= 0` is the same as `N1 =:= N2`, which expresses the intent more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and for the side note, really helpful.